# How can I align MenuBarItem far right of a MenuBar?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am programmatically creating a dijit.MenuBar. After adding several PopupMenuBarItem(s), I am adding a MenuBarItem labelled as 'Logout' and I want it to align right, far from the other Items. I have not seen anything on the samples page to set this alignment property. It should be straight-forward, What am I missing ?

I am using DojoToolkit 1.9 (from Google CDN) but answer for an older version works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a style `float: right;` to the domNode of the 'Logout' MenuBarItem

```
var lo = new MenuBarItem({
    label: "Logout"
});
domStyle.set(lo.domNode, 'float', 'right');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/6Lzdg/

Answer (score 2):

Craig's answer would seem to work in Dojo 1.8.3 but it does not seem to work for me in Dojo 1.9.

I found that I needed to apply additional styling to the parent MenuBar:

```
var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({
   class: "menu"
});
```

Then, in css:

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

You can then add menu items which will appear on left, as usual:

```
pMenuBar.addChild(new MenuBarItem({
    label: "File"
});
```

And you can add menu items (as per Craig's answer) which will appear on the right:

```
var lo = new MenuBarItem({
    label: "Logout"
});

domStyle.set(lo.domNode, 'float', 'right');
```